# Jupyterhub custom spawner start long delays

Tags: python-asyncio, jupyterhub

My custom spawner connects via ssh to a slurm submit node on user's behalf and submits a slurm job.

All of that takes a long time, around 10 seconds if the job can start straight away, which is expected, but I want the user to be redirected to a progress page immediately.

Instead there is a 10 second hang between the user pressing the "start" button and the progress page. It looks like the Jupyterhub waits for the start method to complete before redirecting.

The start method does the following:

```
await for asyncssh connection
await for slurm job to be submitted 
await for a job status to be "Running".
```

So there seems to be a lot of opportunities for Jupyterhub to do other things while the start method is running.

Comment: Hi Yuriy. Note that JupyterHub documentation currently suggests https://discourse.jupyter.org/ is the best place to go for community assistance - probably a better first port of call than SOF.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the issue was related to my spawner using an options_form. Options form causes the spawning process to make a POST request, and in JupyterHub 1.1 POST spawning doesn't go to a pending page.

This behavior is fixed in the current master branch:
https://github.com/jupyterhub/jupyterhub/commit/3908c6d041987e69db7150dcf2041916053b863d